# Маршруты Google API

Tags: google-maps-api

Добрый день, уважаемые хешкодовцы!

У меня возник вопрос. Пытаюсь использовать Google для расчета киллометража между двумя адресами РФ, однако это получается только частично.

Вот так работает
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Воронеж&destination=Выборг&sensor=false&avoid=highways

А вот если использовать, допустим,  Владивосток как город
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Владивосток&destination=Выборг&sensor=false&avoid=highways

то возвращается ZERO_RESULTS. Пожалуйста подскажите, почему так происходит..

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ZERO_RESULTS indicates no route could be found between the origin and destination.

ну не знает Гугль как ехать из Владика в Выборг, не знает.. :)
если вам только по России нужно мерять, то пользуйтесь Яндексом, там больше актуальной информации

Comment: Я пользуюсь Yandex для построения маршрута и определения километража. Но загвоздка в том, что данный километраж я получаю там в реальном времени, при построении карты. Карта строится в профиле пользователя. 

А хотелось бы так: При регистрации пользователя, сразу определить километраж от адреса до адреса и записать его в БД (PHP скриптом я думаю).  

Может подскажите как реализовать такую вот задачку?

Comment: если у вас маршруты статические, неизменные, то пишите утилитку, которая будет сохранять к вам куда-то в базу ответы геокодера. потом будете доставать их из своей базы.